# How can I have different Audio output for Steam Voice chat?

Tags: steam, voice-chat

I was playing Portal 2 today and I wanted to have in-game audio (environmental sounds) through my main desktop speakers, while having my voice chat output to my headset.   I couldn't find the setting to change my default output speakers for voice-chat... I ended up having to put all audio through my headset.

Is there any way I can set output voice to my headset and leave ingame audio to my main speakers?

Comment: What application are you using for voice chat?

Comment: Portal 2 in game voice chat -- embedded with steam.

Comment: Since that's all one source I'm not sure if there is a way for the OS to split up the outputs. I know if you use an application like Skype or Ventrillo you can choose where the application sends the sounds (Headset or speakers), but for an application like Steam, the OS would see it as one source and have to handle it as such.

Comment: +1 - Same problem. It's super annoying that Steam hasn't supported this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a program called [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/) you can choose which audio output a program will play off, unfortunately, splitting the two different sounds from within portal is not possible, so an external voice client must be used (such as steam chat).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, something like this doesn't seem to be supported, yet. Most games allowing you to pick your output device for voice contents will allow you to select a second device/sound card to split output. You could try changing your default communication device under control panel's "Sounds", but I'm not sure if Steam will use/adhere to this choice.

Answer (score -2):

o windows 7 im using those realtek hd audio, then i just chose device advanced settings and choose "make front and rear outputs devices playback different audio streams simultaneously" then there are 2 output devices gonna appear, make sure you also click on the connector settings and uncheck "disable front jack detection" i know its tricky but it would let you have 2 sound outputs without same sound coming out on the speaker in general, now make your speaker the "default device" then the headset as "default communication device" and then it works ihope it helps :D